# Input html - help stopping inheritence of css classes - mixed with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jQuery script, that sends the value of a input box to another box, and also changes the class of the css.

The problem I am having is that the css class is being inherited from another class, so it wont change. If anyone can help me with this. I would be in debt to you for sure.

In order to understand, here is the link to my site(you will need to add an item to the cart to get to the checkout page, but the checkout page is the problem im having.

```
http://%20http://69.195.124.120/~fuseboxg/checkout/
```

When you get to this page, you will see a bunch of boxs that are supposed to have pictures. under the box, there is a input box, when you type in there, and hit the 'choose design' button, it transfers what you typed, to a Design Choice box below that part. but its also supposed to change the class of that input.

So, Here is a link to the jQuery I am using to change classes and  transfer text:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cmqyx/2/)

but my main problem, is that it wont change  the class, i think because it keeps inheriting another class from the div

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems in your JS Fiddle code...

You have defined function `changeID` multiple times (maybe for each button!). Only one function is needed which can be called multiple times from any where in the code in same namespace.

You have multiple instances of document ready `jQuery(function($){...})` binding, which is not necessary. All the relevant code can be combined in one instance.

You are binding click element to each element separately. This can be done by single binding on either `className`, `tagName` or better yet on [**.delegated()**](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to parent element. Note: As of JQuery 1.7 `delegate` has been superseded by [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method.

You are using `toggleClass` JQuery function. This will add or remove the class from only clicked element, not from its siblings (or other input elements). As per my understanding I think that you want to add `butzz` class to clicked button and remove it from  all other buttons (please clarify in comment if that is not the case). This can be done by [`removeClass`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) method on all buttons and [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) on the clicked element.

I have updated your fiddle to reflect all these changes.

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Cmqyx/12/)

As for inheriting `css` rules you should be aware that the rules for children always take precedence, also conflicting styles for same element are applied in the order they appear in the listing. E.g. in the following code both the classes are for same element and if applied together rules from `.butzz` will be applied as it appears after `.butz`.

```
.butz {
    background-color: red;
}

.butzz {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Sometimes when either developer does not have control over all the css styles or for some other unavoidable reason which does not allow the flexibility in css `!important` identifier can be used. Though it should be used with utmost caution as it overrides other conflicting rules for same element, might break some styles and makes future additions in css frustrating.

```
.butzz {
  background-color: green !important;
  /*it will override all other backgroung-color specifications for the element*/
}
```

**Edit:**

Going through your site's code I found that you are binding JQuery inside ready function as a closure. You might be getting "$ is not a function" error. Move the `changeID` function inside the document ready  block. Also remove all the duplicated code. It will save you much precious debug time.

```
jQuery(function($){
    function changeID(elm){
        $('.butz').removeClass('butzz');
        $(elm).addClass('butzz');
    }

    $('.butz').on('click',function(){
        $('#design_choice').val($(this).prev().val());
        changeID(this);
    });
});
```

Give it a try.

**Edit:**

You do not have any css rule defined for `butzz` class! Add the rule in style declaration of the head section.

```
.butzz {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Also your structure has a `<br>` tag between text box and button. use

```
$(this).siblings('input[type="text"]').val()
```

instead of

```
$(this).prev().val()
```

That will change first line of click binding function to

```
$('#design_choice').val($(this).siblings('input[type="text"]').val());
```

[**.prev()**](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)

[**.siblings()**](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

Comment: I have to say, what you have said and the update to the jsfiddle, is great. Thank you much. But I have tried the !important for the css, but it still doesn't want to take the change.

Comment: I checked this out, removed the js that I had on my site and replaced it with this. Although, I would love to use it, and get rid of the duplicate functions, i can't seem to get it to work. I added it to the header and it didn't transfer the value for the box, or change the class. I am absolutely sure the problem with the class, is that I am using genesis with wordpress, and it isn't letting me change the class of the buttons.. It already have a class for input tag, so if I use input
it gives it that class and wont let me use any other class on it. Also, i did find those errors you mentions

Comment: You do not have any CSS rule declaration for `butzz` class. also your HTML structure is slightly different. See my new edit. Hope that solves your problem. You might also want to use Developer Tools (Chrome, Safari) or Firebug (Firefox) to debug the code.

Comment: [Firebug tutorial](http://www-scf.usc.edu/~csci571/Special/Tutorials/firebug-571.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

instead of toggleclass use 
  $(elm).removeClass('butz');
  $(elm).addClass('butzz');
passing a boolena variable
http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/ 
read API

Comment: I did try this however, and it didn't work. It works when I use it in my demo, and through a page by itself, but i believe the problem is with it inheriting another class

Answer (score 0):

Use this...

```
function changeID(elm) {
    if($(elm).hasClass("butz")){
    $(elm).removeClass("butz");
     $(elm).addClass("butzz");
    }else{
          $(elm).removeClass("butzz");
     $(elm).addClass("butz");
    }

}
```

Comment: I have tried this, with one of my last examples, but did not work right on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You neither need 9 `$(function($){...})` nor the function `changeID()` (which you have redeclared 8 times). Instead try the follwing:

```
$(function(){
 $('.butz').click(function(){
  this.className=(this.className=='butz'?'butzz':'butz');
  // console.log(this.className); // just for debugging
  $('#design_choice').val($(this).prev('input').val())
   .removeClass().addClass(this.className);
  // console.log(but.attr('class')); // another debugging output       
 });
});
```

That is the **whole** script.

see here: http://jsfiddle.net/Cmqyx/11/

I moved the (faulty) logic of `changeId()` into the line

```
  this.className=(this.className=='butz'?'butzz':'butz');
```

In this case I can only change between two classes. This can be changed of course to accomodate more classes to be stepped through if necessary.

Comment: cars10, thank you for your response, however, after putting this in my head, it didn't want to do anything. It didn't excute the class change, or the value pass. I played with it on jsfiddle, and it works, but like everything i have tried, it wont  accept the class change for some strange reason. Could you possibly look at the checkout page, and maybe see why its not accepting ?
I looked into the inspect element in chrome and it gives me an error, but i think my main issue is that the button is in a div that has a class, (its on wordpress with woocommerce and genesis), and it wont take

Comment: I have looked at your page http://69.195.124.120/~fuseboxg/cart/ , also filled it with a few items but cannot find anything that resembles the button scenario of the JSfiddle there.